# How can I change the scrolling direction of the mouse, independently of the trackpad?

Tags: mojave, mouse, trackpad, macos

In `System Preferences > Trackpad > Scroll & Zoom`, there is a checkbox called `Scroll Direction: Normal`, which allows us to change the scrolling direction of the trackpad, but it also changes the scrolling direction of the mouse. Is there a way of changing the scrolling direction of the mouse, without changing the scrolling direction of the trackpad?

I have a [Razer: Deathadder Elite](https://www.razer.com/gaming-mice/razer-deathadder-elite) mouse, but I would like the solution to work for different and less sophisticated mouses.

Comment: If you have no trackpad, the scrolling direction is in the Mouse control panel. idk if it's still there as a separate item if you do have one, but worth a look.

Comment: Yes, that was already apparent from your question. Did you look in the Mouse control panel yet?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [Scroll Reverser](https://pilotmoon.com/scrollreverser/), as it appears to do as you've asked.

[image]